# Sum of inverse squares of denominators

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of

$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}, |x|<1}(\mathrm{denominator}\;\; \mathrm{of}\;\; x)^{-2}?$$

(the denominator of a nonzero rational number $x$ is defined to be $b$ where $x=a/b$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, $b\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, and $a,b$ are relatively prime).

Or, is there a "nice" expression for the above sum?

**Edit:** Forgot to write a hypothesis. I'm considering only those rationals with $|x|<1$.

Comment: Does this series even converge in some sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you replace the exponent -2 by -3, then one can show your sum, over nonzero rationals of absoloute value <= 1, ends up converging, to a number bounded above by

$$2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

To see this note that each denominator $n$ appears in $2\phi(n)$ of the terms, and use that $\phi(n) \le n$ for $n \ge 1$. So the contribution from denominator n is at most $2n/(n^3)=2/n^2$.
The extra 2 is from also counting the negative numbers in [-1,0).

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges. Consider when $x$ ranges over just those rational numbers whose denominator is 1, which is strictly less than your sum here.

Comment: Of course. Wait... I'm going to edit my question, as I forgot writing the complete hypothesis (I was actually considering only rationals with $|x|<1$ but I forgot writing it!)

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, and you can use that to prove that even if you only take the rationals with prime denominator, you get divergence.

Comment: Fair enough. Accepted! (I was to hasty in writing the question. In fact, I was trying to invent a nice "exercise" that involved a sum over the rationals and their denominators. Appearently, I failed.  :) )

Comment: It is funny that you, Simplicius, got a simple answer! :P

Comment: Even if this answer is ok, I think I should accept coffeemath's answer instead, because it's more complete.